# The correct database schema for one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema

I’m building a hobby site about cars. If a user clicks on a car I want to display a list of similar cars for the chosen car.

I have a main table witch stores the basic information about each car, CarDataMain, two of the columns in the table are CarID (Pk) and SimilarCarsID (Fk).

I have another table called “SimilarCars”, it has three columns; SimilarCarsID (Pk), CarGroupID and CarID.

So the SimilarCarsID-column in the SimilarCars-table has a relationship with the column SimilarCarsID in the CarDataMain-table.

Is this the correct approach, or “best practice”?

Each car can only belong to one CarGroup (CarGroupID).

Another solution would be to create a third table witch holds the relationship between CarDataMain and SimilarCars-data, but as there is a one-to-many relationship I guess this is over kill? That way I could however put the same foreign key-value in CarDataMain for all cars witch belong to the same CarGroup, witch somehow feels appealing…

A third solution would be to skip the SimilarCarsID column in CarDataMain and make the CarID a foreign key in the SimilarCars table, if you understand what I mean. But I guess there are some drawbacks with that solution…

Sorry for newbie questions (and if this question has been up before), but I want to get it right before I start :)

Ludde

Answer (score 0):

**Note: re-written**

- Design tables that describe things like `Car`, `Group`, others?
- Use "join tables" to give the desired one-to-many relationships.

### Tables

- `CarID` - primary key

#### Group

- `GroupID` - primary key.
- `Name` - the name of the group.

The `GroupID` may not be necessary. If `Name` is unique then use that as the primary key.

#### CarGroup

- `CarID` - foreign key to Car Table
- `GroupID` - foreign key to Group table

This is a join table. Here you can map a given car to many groups, and map a given group to many cars.

#### SimilarCar

I may be misunderstanding, but is seems like you want to match cars as similar, for no particular reason. If you want to match by group, that is above; and if you want "these 2 cars are similar, period", here you go. This is not mutually exclusive to the groups.

- `CarID` - FK to Car table
- `SimilarCarID` - Fk to Car table

A constraint so CarId cannot match SimilarCarID -- unless you do want a car to be similar to itself. But if so then just read the car table instead.

Comment: Without going in to details, let’s just assume that what I described is what I want (a SimilarCars-table). (I had written a detailed explanation why but it contained too many characters, sorry…).

Comment: For details about why I want the SimilarCars-table, please see my answer to JBrooks.  However, the section you wrote about “SimilarCar” above feels spot on! Taking into account my answer to JBrooks, I guess that’s the way to go then? 
Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think your concepts need to be cleared up first. Isn't a "similar car" a car that is in the same "group"? If so, you only need 1 term. Since "group" is a reserved word it is better to use something else.

I would go with the term "category".  So my Cars table would have a CategoryId column. Picture the page on the front-end where someone would add a new car, wouldn't they have a drop down list to select the Category?

So my model would be:

```
Cars
-Id (PK)
-Name
-CategoryId  (FK to Categories)
...

Categories
-Id (PK)
-Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done exactly like your model above. The ”problem” is that cars in the same category can still be very different cars. The user who is looking at a Porche Cayene is not very likely to be interested in a Hyundai Santa Fe, and vice versa. 
So when the user is looking at Porsche Cayenne, cars like BMW X5 and Audi Q7 will be displayed in a list as similar cars. And so on. Hence my SimilarCars-table. :)

Comment: How is that a problem? You state that a car can only be in one group, so the Cayene, BMW X5 and Audi Q7 would be in the same group (their CategoryID would be the same value).

Comment: The user interface has several dropdown lists; Price range, Car category etc. The car category dropdown list displays different car categories; SUV, Family wagons etc, where the name of the category comes from the Name-column in the CarCategory table. If I would use the CarCategory table like you suggest there would be literally hundreds of categories. For that reason the name-column in the CarCategory-table would be useless for the end user, as the categories would have names like “Super-sporty-SUVs”, “a little bit less sporty SUVs” etc. That’s why I want a similar-car-table ALSO. :)

Comment: @Ludde, call one of the categories something else like "CarType". You just described a 1 to many relationship.

Comment: @JBrooks; well, I disagree. The Name-column in the category-table is needless for this "similar car" thing. For that reason, in my opinion radarbobs suggestion below (the SimilarCar-section) seems to be the best. But you are welcome to prove me wrong with some examples. :)